# How can I retrieve the http body?

Tags: c#, c++

I have problem with my code. When i'm sending response in c# server to a c++ client i end up with weird response.

Note: `DownloadData` method is just receiving data from the server, nothing else.

C# Response Handle:

```
void HandleHttpRequest(object client)
{
    HttpListenerContext cc = (HttpListenerContext)client;
    cc.Response.Headers.Add("Test: Foo");
    cc.Response.OutputStream.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Foo"), 0, Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Foo").Length);
    cc.Response.Close();
}
```

C++ Client

```
void DoHttpRead()
{
    char* downloadedHttpBodyAndHeaders = DownloadData("127.0.0.1:49578");
    cout << string(downloadedHttpBodyAndHeaders) << endl;
}
```

DownloadData function

```
char* DownloadData(string url)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {

return "error";
    }

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "49578", &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        WSACleanup();
        return "error";
    }

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ptr = result;
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
        ptr->ai_protocol);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
return "error";
    }
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        WSACleanup();
        return "error";
    }

    int recvbuflen = 10000000;
    char* recvbuf = new char[recvbuflen];
    char sendbuffer[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\nContent-Length: 1\r\n\r\n ";
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuffer, sizeof(sendbuffer), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return response;
    }
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return "error";
    }
    char* received = new char[512];
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    {
        do {
            iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
            if (iResult > 0) {


                if (iResult <= 0)
                    break;

                received = (char*)realloc(recvbuf, iResult + totalBytesRead);

                memcpy(received + totalBytesRead, recvbuf, iResult);
                totalBytesRead += iResult;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        } while (iResult > 0);
    }
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    char* received2 = new char[totalBytesRead];
    memcpy(received2, received, totalBytesRead);
    delete[] received;
    return received2;
}
```

The C++ Client Http Body is messed up. Instead of just "Foo" it appears like

```
//headers

e

Foo
8
```

How can I get only Foo text in the http body?

Comment: Are you using some specific library or what? There could be billion problems in your current code that you are not showing us.

Comment: No. Just `winsock2.h`

Comment: Please show your actual `DownloadData()` code, it is obviously doing something wrong, but we can't see it. Also, `DoHttpRead()` appears to have a memory leak, why is `DownloadData()` returning a raw pointer (to what exactly?) and not a `std::string` or `std::vector` container? Also, you should not be calling `Encoding.Default.GetBytes()` twice, that is wasted overhead. Call it once and store the result to a local variable that you then use in your call to `Write()`.

Comment: Added `DownloadData()` Code.

Comment: `DownloadData()` takes a `new`-ed char array, and `realloc()`s it. You can't do that in C++. That's one confirmed fail. Not to mention the fact that there is no logical need to reallocate anything, here. By using C++ containers logically, there is no reason, whatsoever, to `new` anything. Everything done here can be done safely, using vectors. Another bug is that `GET` requests do not specify `Content-Length`. Your server probably goes LOL, at that idea.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik actually, the latest HTTP 1.1 spec allows content bodies in `GET` requests. But in this case, the code is not sending a body, but it is sending a `Content-Length: 1` header when it should be sending `Content-Length: 0` instead. And it is also missing a `Connection: close` header to ask the server to close the socket connection at the end of the response, as HTTP 1.1 keeps the connection alive by default.

Comment: So i have to replace the method of receiving data or something else to solve  the issue? Note i tried sending same using POST and same http body response